# CSS nested div height 100% doesn't work

Tags: html, css, height

I hope that someone can help me about this problem. I have structure like this

```
<div id="Div1" style="height:auto">
 <div id="Div2" style="height:100%;">
  <div id="Div3" style="min-height:100%;"></div>
  <div id="Div4" style="height:100%;"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Also I put in my css file

```
html,body
{
  height: 100%;
}
```

Problem is that neither Div3 nor Div4 have the expected height of 100%, I check size of first two divs with firbug and they are ok, filling the whole screen.

Sorry for my bad English, I hope that you understand my question :)

Comment: `#Div1` should have some height to let its child elements stretch in it.

Comment: Set #Div1 { height: 100%; }
Also the height you set for Div4 should be in a style attribute.

Comment: you must define a height for outermost div that named `Div1`

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply :) I have read that first div must have a defined height so that others might inherit, but i can't set  fixed height because site size changing. I hope that can set #Div1 height like 100% or something like that

Comment: `html, body { height: 100%; }` is the magic sauce :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this. When using a percentage, each `div` will be affected by the height of it's parent.

In this example the `html,body` has a height of `100%` and the percentage of each div child is then relative to it's parent. Note how each `div` is half the size of it's parent `div`, each step it shrinks by half the size.

**Updated with all percentage example**

[Simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/maLfb/3/)

HTML

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
div {
    height: 100%;
    background: #F00;
}
div div {
    background: #FF0;
    height: 50%;
}
div div div {
    background: #000;
    height: 50%;
}
div div div div {
    background: #F30;
    height: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all write height in inline style

```
 <div id="Div4" height:100%;"></div>
```

change to

```
 <div id="Div4" style="height:100%;"></div>
```

Comment: It was a spelling mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

The key is to set the height of the div with id "Div1" to something other than "auto". Try 100% or a specific value like this

```
<div id="Div1" style="height:100%;">
<div id="Div2" style="height:100%;">
<div id="Div3" style="min-height:100%;"></div>
<div id="Div4" height:100%;"></div>
</div>
</div>
```